# Recurrence $k$-th pattern by substitution

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

The recurrence is $T(n) = 9 T(\frac{n}{3}) + {n^2}$.
Simplified to ${3^2} T(\frac{n}{3}) + {n^2}$. Then

$$\begin{align}
T(n)&= 3^4T(\frac{n}{3^2}) + 4n\\
&= 3^6T(\frac{n}{3^3}) + 10n\\
&= 3^8T(\frac{n}{3^4}) + 28 n.
\end{align}$$

I am trying to find the $k$-th pattern of this recurrence.

Comment: How did you determine these were equivalent expressions?

Comment: What if $3\nmid n$? Or do you need only $T_k=T(3^k)$? (In the latter case, you get a first-order linear recurrence $T_k=9T_{k-1}+9^k$ which is easily solved: $T_k=(T_0+k)9^k$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion something is wrong in your approach.

If $T(n)={3^2} T(\frac{n}{3}) + {n^2}$, then $T(\frac{n}{3^k})={3^2} T(\frac{n}{3^{k+1}}) + (\frac{n}{3^k})^2$ and
$$\begin{align}T(n)&={3^2} T(\frac{n}{3}) + {n^2}={3^2} \left({3^2} T(\frac{n}{3^2}) + \frac{n^2}{3^2}\right) + n^2\\
&={3^4} T(\frac{n}{3^2})  + 2n^2
={3^4} \left({3^2} T(\frac{n}{3^3}) + \frac{n^2}{3^4}\right) + 2n^2\\
&={3^6} T(\frac{n}{3^3})  + 3n^2=\dots={9^k} T(\frac{n}{3^k})  + kn^2.\\
\end{align}$$

P.S. Do you know the [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Generic_form)?

Comment: I don't, but I understand where I went wrong - thanks!